# C++ - return 0 vs. return -1

Tags: c++, return

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What should main() return in C/C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/204476/what-should-main-return-in-c-c)

In C++, `return 0` tells that the program has ended successfuly.

What about `return -1`? Does it break (halt) the program?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer: no.  Returning anything except 0 just means that there was an error.

Comment: Nitpicking: eturning `EXIT_SUCCESS` also signifies success, and `EXIT_SUCCESS` can be different from 0.

Answer (score 1):

No, it just sets the return_code environment variable in the shell, with which you can determine whether the program returned fine or with error when you use batch processing.

Windows:

```
echo %errorlevel%
```

POSIX:

```
echo $?
```

BTW, use EXIT_SUCCESS and EXIT_FAILURE defined in cstdlib

Answer (score 0):

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/libs/system/doc/index.html#Acknowledgements

Here you can find nice library for system error types.